# How can I split a string in LESS?

Tags: css, less, lesscss-resources

In Stylus it's as easy as `split('1/2', '/')[0]` (which will split a string value at a certain delimiter, in the example it would return `1`), in Sass I needed a huge function to do it. I don't see a way to natively do this in LESS or a function for doing this anywhere.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Where did you find a `split` function in Stylus?

Comment: It's actually undocumented but definitely exists. https://github.com/stylus/stylus/blob/c2d07a0f117de6144105de8599f620c34713d251/lib/functions/index.js#L1083

Comment: I see, thank you. Given that it is undocumented, you might want to describe what it does in your question, since it is not obvious what it does without reading the code.

Comment: It is certainly a better question now. Unfortunately I still don't have an answer for you, except to point you [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1465), using recursion and [`extract`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract). It is limited to space- and comma-separated lists though.

Comment: Appreciate it. Currently trying to implement my own version of something like that. It's silly more of these functions aren't built into preprocessors. I see now why people talk about PostCSS being the be-all, end-all, for offering this kind of control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's silly more of these functions aren't built into preprocessors.

You should possible also explain why you need the `split` function.

Since Less version 2 you can easily add your own functions, see [How to exend the Less compiler with a custom function leveraging a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809514/how-to-exend-the-less-compiler-with-a-custom-function-leveraging-a-plugin)

You should be able to add a `split` function which returns a list. As already explained by @Amadan you can use this list with [loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) and the built-in [list functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions).

Comment: I need to split strings so I can grab the denominator from a fraction and use it in my grid's calculations. I've figured out a way to do this by changing the syntax specifically for LESS (extracting something like `1 of 2` works well), but it's not ideal since it doesn't match the other preprocessors (`'1/2'`) but I don't feel like fighting with it anymore so it'll have to do.